# Room query return LiveData of parent class type

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm having three clases:

- Task (parent class)
- ProgressTask (subclass of Task)
- TodolistTask (subclass of Task)

ProgressTask and TodolistTask differ by few parameters.

Both ProgressTask and TodolistTask are entities in my Room db.
I want to have TaskDao in which I would like to call this query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM  progressTask_table UNION SELECT * FROM todolistTask_table")
LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks();
```

is it possible? Now I'm getting a reasonable error saying that SELECTs to the left and right have different number of columns.

Comment: If you post your Task, ProgressTask, and TodolistTask I can be more specific in my answer.

Comment: For me your answer is crystal clear I could quickly fix my query (thanks), so I don't really think that it's necessary to add those classes without them question is more clear. I've added a quick note saying that those classes differ by few parameters,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call out the individual columns in you query when using a union.

You objects most likely have different columns. Example ProgressTask has a date that TodolistTask doesn't.

If you call out each column in the base class in both select parts of your query it will work.